# Flutter project build issues on Moto e22 running Android 12

Tags: java, android, flutter, logcat

**Description**:
I recently purchased a Moto e22 device running Android 12 and encountered several issues while trying to build my Flutter project using Android Studio.

**First Problem:**
After creating a new Flutter project with no modifications, when I attempted to run the project from Android Studio using the play button, the build succeeded, but I encountered a white screen with no logs in the run tab. However, if I manually kill the app and relaunch it on the Android device without any further build from Android Studio, it runs without any issues.

**Second Problem:**
When I tried running the project using flutter run --verbose or flutter run --debug, the app installed successfully on my Android device, but I got stuck with the message "Waiting for VM Service port to be available" or "Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk" without any further actions such as hot reload or hot restart.

Here's a summary of my Flutter doctor output:

this is my flutter doctor summary

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel main, 3.21.0-17.0.pre.19, on macOS 12.6.8 21G725 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    ! CocoaPods 1.12.1 out of date (1.13.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#updating-cocoapods for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I've attempted various solutions found in threads, including changing the Flutter channel, but the issues persist.

Here's the output of my logcat:

```
2024-03-29 06:58:54.905   669-830   UxUtility               ven...hardware.mtkpower@1.0-service  E  notifyAppState error = NULL
2024-03-29 06:58:54.926  2937-2937  PhoneInterfaceManager   com.android.phone                    E  [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntentAndPhone: No UICC
2024-03-29 06:58:54.943  3886-3886  AidRoutingManager       com.android.nfc                      E  Size of routing table804
2024-03-29 06:58:54.958   681-681   BpTransact...edListener surfaceflinger                       E  Failed to transact (-32)
2024-03-29 06:58:54.958   681-681   BpTransact...edListener surfaceflinger                       E  Failed to transact (-32)
2024-03-29 06:58:54.986   681-834   BufferQueueDebug        surfaceflinger                       E  [com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings#0](this:0xb400007a470532e8,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings#0'
2024-03-29 06:58:55.381   681-834   BufferQueueDebug        surfaceflinger                       E  [Splash Screen com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project#0](this:0xb400007a47069f68,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'Splash Screen com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project#0'
2024-03-29 06:58:55.494   669-830   UxUtility               ven...hardware.mtkpower@1.0-service  E  notifyAppState error = NULL
2024-03-29 06:58:55.633  6026-6043  OpenGLRenderer          com.android.settings                 E  EglManager::makeCurrent mED = 0x1, surface = 0x0, mEC = 0xb4000078bd6be650, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2024-03-29 06:58:55.741  6249-6271  QT                      pid-6249                             E  [QT]file does not exist
2024-03-29 06:58:56.370   681-835   BufferQueueDebug        surfaceflinger                       E  [com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project/com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project.MainActivity#0](this:0xb400007a47042188,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project/com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project.MainActivity#0'
2024-03-29 06:58:56.400  6249-6269  OpenGLRenderer          com...driverapp.new_flutter_project  E  EglManager::makeCurrent mED = 0x1, surface = 0x0, mEC = 0xb4000078bd6b8110, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2024-03-29 06:58:56.400   681-835   BufferQueueDebug        surfaceflinger                       E  [SurfaceView[com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project/com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project.MainActivity](BLAST)#0](this:0xb400007a47056078,id:-1,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) id info cannot be read from 'SurfaceView[com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project/com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project.MainActivity](BLAST)#0'
2024-03-29 06:58:56.407   681-835   HWComposer              surfaceflinger                       E  getSupportedContentTypes: getSupportedContentTypes failed for display 0: Unsupported (8)
2024-03-29 06:58:56.413  6249-6276  ion                     com...driverapp.new_flutter_project  E  ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2024-03-29 06:59:00.457 24427-4404  WakeLock                com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2024-03-29 06:59:00.470  6249-6269  OpenGLRenderer          com...driverapp.new_flutter_project  E  fbcNotifyFrameComplete error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyFrameComplete
2024-03-29 06:59:00.470  6249-6269  OpenGLRenderer          com...driverapp.new_flutter_project  E  fbcNotifyNoRender error: undefined symbol: fbcNotifyNoRender
```

Complete Output of flutter run --verbos

```
[  +13 ms] Stopping app 'app-debug.apk' on moto e22.
[   +1 ms] executing: /Users/ibtihajnaeem/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ZE2235Q3DM shell am force-stop
com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project
[ +202 ms] executing: /Users/ibtihajnaeem/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ZE2235Q3DM shell pm list packages
com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project
[ +106 ms] package:com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project
[   +5 ms] executing: /Users/ibtihajnaeem/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ZE2235Q3DM shell cat
/data/local/tmp/sky.com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project.sha1
[  +85 ms] d398535fddb940e49abe5dd0a43b3932ccf5e1be
[   +1 ms] Latest build already installed.
[   +2 ms] executing: /Users/ibtihajnaeem/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ZE2235Q3DM shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +92 ms] --------- beginning of main
           03-29 07:25:16.521 E/BpTransactionCompletedListener(  681): Failed to transact (-32)
[  +21 ms] executing: /Users/ibtihajnaeem/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ZE2235Q3DM shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c
android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true
com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project/com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project.MainActivity
[ +124 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000
cmp=com.whimstech.driverapp.new_flutter_project/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +1 ms] Waiting for VM Service port to be available...
```

Comment: whats your `flutter run --verbose ...` command output?

Comment: Waiting for VM Service port to be available

Comment: and the lines before (without all gradle stuff)?

Comment: I had updated my description you can see it at the end of my question

Comment: does `flutter devices --verbose` show anything interesting / suspicious ?

Comment: No I didn't find anything suspicious. everything looks normal to me